# mongo2.6: db.serverStatus().connections nothing happened?

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to create a user,and got authorize error.
So I modify the `/etc/mongod.conf` :

```
#auth=True
```

And then restart the mongo,and create the user on terminal :

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "superAdmin",
    pwd: "    ",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

It was success,then I modify `/etc/mongod.conf`  back to  :

```
auth=True
```

And I use remote login with `robomongo`
And I want to check `db.serverStatus().connections`
But nothing happened?
How can I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `userAdminAnyDatabase` role does not grant access to run the `serverStatus` command. Your `db.serverStatus()` command is returning an authorization error and you are then referencing a non-existent `connections` property which results in the "no results to show" message.

You can confirm this by running `db.serverStatus()`, which should return something similar to the following if the current user is not authorized:

```
{
     "ok" : 0,
     "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { serverStatus: 1.0 }",
     "code" : 13
}
```

To allow the `serverStatus` command you need to grant either a built-in role that includes this privilege ([`clusterMonitor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterMonitor) or [`hostManager`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/built-in-roles/#hostManager) in MongoDB 2.6) or [create a user-defined role](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/define-roles/#define-roles) if you want a more narrow scope.

For example, to create and grant a custom role to run serverStatus:

```
use admin
db.createRole({
    role: "serverStatus",
    privileges: [
        { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "serverStatus" ] },
    ],
    roles: []
})

db.grantRolesToUser("superAdmin",["serverStatus"])
```